# React-redux: How to bubble up redux form props to parent component

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-redux-form

So I've been in the process of getting a modal form implemented that allows me to create new users in a list, as well as edit them. I've set it up so that my actual form inside the Modal is in its own component so I can easily pass `initialValues` to the form for it to be populated. The problem I'm running into is now when I try to utilize redux's `handleSubmit` function, I can't seem to `.get()` the field values from the form, as it keeps telling me that `.get()` is not a function. I've seen this work before, so I'm not exactly sure what I'm doing wrong.

To keep things as short as possible, here is render() method in the component that contains the form:

```
render() {
    const { handleSubmit, pristine, reset, submitting } = this.props;
    return (
      <form>
       <div>
           <Field
             name="first_name"
             component={TextField}
             hintText="First Name"
           />
       </div>
       <RaisedButton label="Update user" style={{marginRight: "10px"}} disabled={pristine || submitting} onClick={handleSubmit} primary={true} />
      </form>
   )
}
```

And here is the render method from the parent component:

```
render() {
   return (
     <Dialog
                  title={this.state.modalTitle}
                  modal={false}
                  open={this.state.userModalOpen}
                  onRequestClose={this.handleClose}
                >
                  <ManageUserform
                    isEditingUser={this.state.isEditingUser}
                    handleSubmit={this.submit}
                    handleClose={this.handleClose}
                    initialValues={this.state.user}/>
                </Dialog>

   )
}
```

Here is my actual `submit()` function that does run when the form gets submitted:

```
/**
   *  Submit the user form
   */
  submit(formProps) {

    const user = {
      first_name: formProps.get('first_name')
    };

    // Are we editing?
    if(this.state.isEditingUser) {
      user['_id'] = this.state.user.id;
      this.props.dispatch(updateUser(user));
    } else {
      // Dispatch action to convert the request to a work order
      this.props.dispatch(createUser(user));
    }

    // Close the modal
    this.handleClose();
  }
```

^ And this is where the problem lies. When I submit, I get an error:

`Uncaught TypeError: formProps.get is not a function`.

Previously, when I had the form directly in the parent component, I was able to use the `formProps.get()` method, but now there's something going on where because it's inside of a component, it's not bubbling up to its parent component. Is there something small I'm missing here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is formProps? Put a `debugger;` in the submit function and take a look.

Answer (score 0):

because you changed function invoke context, you should call it using bind method and you should set new `this`. Try to change `onClick={handleSubmit.bind(this)}`.

Comment: hey ksh, thanks for the response. For the bind to `this`, where are you saying to make this happen. I don't have a `handleClick` function in my component. Is this referring to the `handleSubmit`? Because if so, I tried, and I'm still getting that error :/

Comment: sorry, it should be `onClick={handleSubmit.bind(this)}`, if it still don't work, import your function to your component `import { submit } from 'yourLocation';`

Comment: I realized I needed to change my handleSubmit call to onSubmit. You can see my answer

Answer (score 0):

So with redux form, when you run `handleSubmit`, the component looks for an `onSubmit`, so I needed to change my component's props to reflect that. Here is my updated render method code for my parent component:

```
render() {
   return (
     <Dialog
                  title={this.state.modalTitle}
                  modal={false}
                  open={this.state.userModalOpen}
                  onRequestClose={this.handleClose}
                >
                  <ManageUserform
                    isEditingUser={this.state.isEditingUser}
                    onSubmit={this.submit}
                    handleClose={this.handleClose}
                    initialValues={this.state.user}/>
                </Dialog>

   )
}
```